# Compressed ETC texture update in Android - glCompressedTexSubImage2D

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, texture-mapping

I can successfully create and load ETC textures in Android,
using the calls:

```
ETC1Texture etc1tex = new ETC1Texture(...);
gl11.glCompressedTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0/*level*/, 
                             ETC1.ETC1_RGB8_OES/*internal format*/,  
                 etc1tex.getWidth(), etc1tex.getHeight(),        
                 0/*border*/,   
                 etc1tex.getData().capacity()/*imagesize*/, 
                 etc1tex.getData());
```

But now i need to update this texture with new image data.
I am using the call to SubImage :

```
GL11.glCompressedTexSubImage2D( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0/*level*/,                    
            0,   0,     etc1tex.getWidth(), etc1tex.getHeight(),        
            ETC1.ETC1_RGB8_OES, 
            etc1tex.getData().capacity(), 
            etc1tex.getData());
```

which takes more or less the same paramaters, as previous call. 
But its not working, my texture does'nt even change a bit.

But If i simply replace the SubImage call with the first one, i can see some distortion in the texture when it updates...

Does anyone know how i can use this CompressedTexSubImage call

Comment: I know it's been two years but did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

yeah ,i meet the same problem.

i use `glCompressedTexImage2D(texinfo.glTarget + face, level,glInternalFormat, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 0,faceLodSize, data);`

it works.

but when i use

```
glCompressedTexImage2D(texinfo.glTarget + face, level,glInternalFormat, pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 0,faceLodSize, NULL);
```

and then

```
glCompressedTexSubImage2D(texinfo.glTarget + face, level, 0, 0, pixelWidth , pixelHeight , glInternalFormat,faceLodSize, data);
```

it dose not work.

```
gl error is GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

i need to use `glCompressedTexSubImage2D`,because i load one texture not in one buffer .
may be load  into more than one tile buffer.
if one tile loaded completed, than call `glCompressedTexSubImage2D` to handle it.

Comment: is etc does not support glCompressedTexSubImage2D?
or there is something need to do?
thanks?

Answer (score 0):

According to the API (https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glCompressedTexSubImage2D.xml)

> "The required paletted formats do not allow subimage updates, but
>   other formats defined by extensions may."

I assume this means that for ETC1 compression, subimage just isn't allowed.